# Is a morphism with finite fibers birational?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of projective varieties such that its fibers have finitely many points. Is $f$ birational on its image?

Thanks.

Comment: A birational map is generically one-to-one, by definition.

Comment: Ok, but which are the isomorphic open sets?

Comment: Dear rla, I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no in general. $X$ and $Y$ can be two smooth projective curves of different genera which are by no means birational.

Comment: Dear @Robert you are right. I made a tremendous confusion. I am trying to show that a certain divisor is big, what is sufficient to show that its associated morphism has finite fibers. This guarantees that the morphism associated to a tensor power of the divisor is birational and not necessarily the morphism associated to the divisor. Thanks.